# How to use a Three.js curve as a path for moving a mesh along at

Tags: javascript, three.js, coffeescript

Building an animation, currently in this state:

http://jsfiddle.net/CoderX99/66b3j9wa/1/

Please don't go through the code, it's compiled from CoffeeScript and not good for your sanity.

For your idea, your looking at some "nordic" landscape, where ships float by and cars move on. The yellow sphere in the top left is a representation of a car, and there are winding roads represented by curves.

`CatmullRomCurve3`'s to be exact. The yellow sphere should use the curves to move along at.

Let's use the closed curve, it's coded like so:

```
curveRoadNo2 = new THREE.CatmullRomCurve3([
  new THREE.Vector3( 15, roadHeight, 11 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 12, roadHeight, 12 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 11, roadHeight, 11 ),     
  new THREE.Vector3( 11, roadHeight, 9 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 12, roadHeight, 8 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 12, roadHeight, 5 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 15, roadHeight, 3 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 17, roadHeight, 7 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 16, roadHeight, 8 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 16, roadHeight, 9 ),
  new THREE.Vector3( 17, roadHeight, 11 )
] )
```

Randomly entered.

Then:

```
curveRoadNo2.closed = true
geometry = new THREE.Geometry()
geometry.vertices = curveRoadNo2.getPoints( 200 )
material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xa9c41e } )
curveObject = new THREE.Line( geometry, material )
scene.add( curveObject )
```

And I want to animate somehow using `getPoint(t)` and `getTangent(t)` but am a little clueless.

```
t = 0
animate = ->
  requestAnimationFrame animate

  t += 0.1
  vehicle.position = curveRoadNo2.getPoint(t)

  # (Not per se relevant)
  # The following works for animating the ship but makes 
  # absolutely no sense yet. 
  # Also this should move along some kind of an elliptical path,
  # showing up on to the scene, making a stop for unloading,
  # moving again. And loop.  
  # if 0 < t < 7
  #     v = t * 0.01
  #     ship.rotation.y += 26 * v ** 0.96 * Math.PI / 180
  #     ship.position.x += -6 * v
  #     ship.position.z +=  12 * v ** 1.3 

  renderer.render scene, camera
animate()
```

As one can see the vehicle stays motionless. I looked up solutions, but they all seemed very verbose and overly complicated.

JS answers are of course also welcome.

Comment: I can't get it to pick up my CDN three js r87 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define another vector for a position

```
  animate = function() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    t += 0.001;
    var pos =  curveRoadNo2.getPoint(t);
    vehicle.position.set(pos.x, pos.y, pos.z);
    // if 0 < t < 7
    //     v = t * 0.01
    //     ship.rotation.y += 26 * v ** 0.96 * Math.PI / 180
    //     ship.position.x += -6 * v
    //     ship.position.z +=  12 * v ** 1.3 
    return renderer.render(scene, camera);
  };
```

And t += 0.1 was too fast. So, I made it 0.001.
If you are giving a position for an Object3D or a Mesh. 
Use,

```
mesh.position.set(x, y, z);
object.position.set(newPos.x, newPos.y, newPos.z);
```

Not only positions. For rotations, too.

This is more healthy.

Comment: Just a small remark, `vehicle.position.copy(pos);` is shorter.

Comment: Thanks, you both. I have the issue fixed, see http://jsfiddle.net/CoderX99/66b3j9wa/5/. Two new issues arris, which I tried to illustrate in this new fiddle: When the 'vehicle'-object is moving along an unclosed path, how do I turn it around at the end of the path. (It's simply moving through space to 'position zero' again.) And then the rotation. How do I rotate according to the tangent. Logging the tangent didn't gave me an y-value, which is exactly the axis I need obviously and the only one relevant you'd think for a curve laying in the x-z-plane.

Comment: @Code-MonKy I'd use Tween.js, if animation is more complex than just one object has to move from one point to another.

Comment: Tween.js seems a good one to handle this issue. Thanks, and I'll leave the further solving of that part outside of the scope of this question. That leaves me with the y-axis rotation issue.

Comment: Any ideas on how to apply the result of `getTangent(t)` to my object (ship) such that it points in the right direction? I tried `lookAt(tangent)` but this is more than a few degrees off and turns the wrong direction.